# TemplateNotFound When Deployed to Google App Engine Site

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

**Updated: Feb, 22** Per Lipis's request. I added the code to render the template.

I developed an admin section on my website which worked fine in my local environment  (localhost:8080). When I deployed the application to my appengine site I get the `TemplateNotFound` error when I navigate to *http: //myapp/myadmin/* which should pick up the default.html file in the admin directory.  The html file lives under the templates\admin directory.

The file structure for my templates are:

```
--app
  --templates
    --admin
          -default.html 
    -file.html
    -file1.html
    -file2.html
```

I am using the following code to create the Jinja environment:

```
FolderPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
        [
            os.path.join(FolderPath,"templates\\admin"),
            os.path.join(FolderPath,"templates")
        ]
    )
)
```

**Updated -- Template Render Code:**

```
template_values = {}

template = jinja_environment.get_template('default.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

I am assuming its the "FolderPath" variable that is causing the problem but not 100% sure.   Has anyone run into this problem?

- Language: python 2.7
- OS: Windows 7
- IDE: PyCharms 2.7

**ERROR:**

> default.html Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py",
>   line 1511, in **call**
>       rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py",
>   line 1505, in **call**
>       rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py",
>   line 1253, in default_dispatcher
>       return route.handler_adapter(request, response)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py",
>   line 1077, in **call**
>       return handler.dispatch()   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py",
>   line 547, in dispatch
>       return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py",
>   line 545, in dispatch
>       return method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/0-2-5.365473085936457098/app/controllers/admin.py",
>   line 42, in get
>       template = jinja_environment.get_template('default.html')   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py",
>   line 719, in get_template
>       return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))   File
>   "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py",
>   line 693, in _load_template
>       template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py",
>   line 115, in load
>       source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)   File
>   "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py",
>   line 180, in get_source
>       raise TemplateNotFound(template) TemplateNotFound: default.html

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you also paste your python code when you are rendering the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"templates/admin"`. That backslash thing is a Windows-ism.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally use Linux (Possibly Ubuntu or Mint) It will save you headaches in the long run as well

Comment: Thanks for the advice peterretief, but that doesn't answer my question.